# Why is output from gsettings list-recursively slightly different when run from cron

Tags: cron, gsettings

I have run `gsettings list-recursively` locally from the terminal while logged into X11 on Ubuntu 20.04. Then I also configured a user-based cron job to run `gsettings list-recursively` from the cron and save it into the file. When I compare contents of those files they are slightly different: some entries have different values. But some entries which I know I changed do match. Why are there differences?

I have read around about `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` but I am not setting it for the cron job and it seems `gsettings` still works (but output is slightly different).

Comment: Have you tried setting the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` in cron and running it?

Comment: No difference. Also no difference if I remove `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` from local session (I still get the same output as with it).